# Why does drop() method in Scala allow negative value and does not throw error?

Tags: string, scala, scala-collections

I am trying to get my hands dirty with Scala where is I am playing with `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps` on the terminal. In the String method `drop()`, I tried executing this code

```
"stackoverflow".drop(-12)
```

and the output I received was

`stackoverflow`

The `-12` was a typo but this result is unexpected as it should truncate 12 characters from last or be an error or exception. Because when we pass an integer into the drop(), it eliminates the first characters from the string equivalent to the number of arguments. Why is this behavior kept with this method in Scala? Can this become useful in some scenarios? What is the reason for this behavior?

Scala has many other different behaviors that other languages don't support such as

`true > false` is `true` and `true < false` is `false`.

Comment: The result seems to be `stackoverflow` (the original input), not `tackoverflow`. Right?

Comment: Oh @Tzach, yes. You're right.

Comment: `take()` and `drop()` are designed to be very forgiving. If the argument is less than zero it is adjusted to `0`. If the argument is greater than the current collection length it is adjusted to the collection length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says "If n is negative, don't drop any elements". I'm guessing the reason is that in some cases it lets you skip doing some math. For instance, let's say you want to drop from the start of two strings so that they are equal length. You could do:

```
def makeSameLength(s1: String, s2: String): (String, String) = {
  (s1.drop(s1.size-s2.size), s2.drop(s2.size-s1.size))
}
```

Cases like this where you have to drop some variable number of elements from a sequence come up a lot, and usually if the math works out to a negative number, that means you just don't want to drop anything at all. So this saves you from having to add in some conditional logic, or include a `max(x, 0)` or similar.

I do agree it's a bit surprising, but can see why it might be useful.